# Yii2 relation duplicate when use inner join and jeft join

Tags: php, sql, yii2, relation

There are 3 Models with relation between themselves.
Example

```
class A extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName(){
        return 'tbl_a';
    }
    public function getB()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(B::className(), ['column' => 'column']);
    }
}

class B extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName(){
        return 'tbl_b';
    }
    public function getC()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(C::className(), ['column' => 'column']);
    }
}
```

I have next code:

```
$result = A::find()->joinWith('b')->where('');
if () {
    A->joinWith('b.c')->where('');
}
$result->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

And outcome I have next sql:

```
select * from tbl_a left join tbl_b on ... join tbl_b on ... join tbl_c on ... where ...
```

As you can see sql query duplicates table relation 'tbl_b'. Do you know why?

**UPDATE**

OK, I researched my problem in more detail.
Table connection is duplicated if used different JOIN types.
Next original models:

```
class Myuser extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName(){
        return 'myuser';
    }

    public function getProfile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
    }
}

class Profile extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName(){
        return 'profile';
    }

    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(City::className(), ['id'=>'city_id']);
    }
}
```

Executed code:

```
$get_city = 1;
$u = Myuser::find()->joinWith('profile', 0, 'INNER JOIN');
if ($get_city) {
    $u->joinWith('profile.city');
}
echo $u->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

Result:

```
SELECT `myuser`.* FROM `myuser` 
    INNER JOIN `profile` ON `myuser`.`id` = `profile`.`user_id`
    LEFT JOIN `profile` ON `myuser`.`id` = `profile`.`user_id`
    LEFT JOIN `city` ON `profile`.`city_id` = `city`.`id`
```

How can I avoid repetition, if I need to get a unique table 'profile' and add fields from the table 'city'. If there are no the fields in table 'city', then value should be 'null'.

Comment: Can you show some real code here as an example? These code snippets are not valid PHP code, so it is hard to understand your question.

Comment: whats with `A->joinWith('b.c')->where('');` tha doesnt seem to help

Comment: @rob006
I update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's kind a bug (or feature) in the framework. When you use relation `profile.city` framework doosn't see relation already joined by `inner join`... I assume that if you use `left join` for first relation, everything will work fine.

In your case try to use `leftJoin()` and specify the table name to join:

```
$get_city = 1;
$u = Myuser::find()->innerJoinWith('profile');
if ($get_city) {
    $u->leftJoin('city', 'profile.city_id = city.id');
}
echo $u->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

Comment: You are right, I did it too. But I want to use the relation)

Comment: So, it answer for me now.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're using different join type for these two joins. `joinWith('profile', false, 'INNER JOIN')` and `joinWith('profile')` will generate different `JOIN` (`joinWith()` uses `LEFT JOIN` as join type by default), so you have 2 joins you query. If you want to avoid duplicates, you may use the same settings for these two `joinWith()` calls:

```
$get_city = 1;
$u = Myuser::find()->joinWith('profile', false, 'INNER JOIN');
if ($get_city) {
    $u->joinWith('profile.city', false, 'INNER JOIN');
}
echo $u->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

Result:

```sql
SELECT `myuser`.* FROM `myuser` INNER JOIN `profile` ON `myuser`.`id` = `profile`.`user_id` INNER JOIN `city` ON `profile`.`city_id` = `city`.`id`
```

---

If you want to combine `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`, you may use extended syntax:

```
$get_city = 1;
if ($get_city) {
    $u = Myuser::find()->joinWith(
        [
            'profile' => function (ActiveQuery $query) {
                $query->joinWith('city');
            },
        ],
        false,
        'INNER JOIN'
    );
} else {
    $u = Myuser::find()->joinWith('profile', false, 'INNER JOIN');
}
echo $u->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

Result:

```sql
SELECT `myuser`.* FROM `myuser` INNER JOIN `profile` ON `myuser`.`id` = `profile`.`user_id` LEFT JOIN `city` ON `profile`.`city_id` = `city`.`id`
```

Comment: OK, what you will tell me about it.

`$get_city = 1;
$u = Myuser::find()->joinWith('profile', 0, 'INNER JOIN');
if ($get_city) {
    $u->joinWith('profile.city');
}
$get_country = 1;
$u = Myuser::find()->joinWith('profile', 0, 'INNER JOIN');
if ($get_country ) {
    $u->joinWith('profile.get_country');
}
echo $u->createCommand()->rawSql;`

Answer (score 0):

If you have several relations to the same table, you should use different alias for them. If not, Yii will join to the table, causing an error or duplicates

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).